# Ineffective purging of a flame monitor lens

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-engineering, boilers

There is a wall-opposed flame monitor detecting coal, oil and gas combustion in the burners, attached to the furnace walls in a coal-fired power plant.

I'm looking for suggestions to clear the dust or particulates from the lens, as it is affecting the signal and leads to tripping.

Right now, it is cleaned by supplying purged air from the core air fan. However, this has been found to not be effective as the contaminants still exist.

What would be the cause of such an ineffective system? Could the purge air system be improved by using higher pressure air from other components?

Much appreciated

Comment: Well, what are the contaminants, and what is required to clean them when you bring the lens to a lab bench?

Comment: If the lens isn't being continuously cleaned/purged the frequency of purging may need to be increased. The other thing to considering is the air from the core fan dust free.

Comment: @Fred sorry I do not understand what you mean by "air from the core fan dust free". Do you mean that the purge air itself should be free of dust?

Comment: @Urvil: Yes. Blowing dusty air onto the lens will not help